# How do I overlay ActivityIndicator in react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a View with few form elements and a button (TouchableHighlight). On clicking the button, an Activity Indicator should be shown as an overlay to the existing view. The Activity Indicator should be centered within the page and the existing view should be slightly blurred to indicate overlay. I tried different options but could not get it to work.

```
render() {
    const { username, password } = this.state;

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.group}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Username:</Text>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    onChangeText={this.handleUserNameChange.bind(this)}
                    value={username}
                    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.group}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Password:</Text>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                    onChangeText={this.handlePasswordChange.bind(this)}
                    value={password}
                    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                />
            </View>
            <TouchableHighlight
                style={styles.button}
                onPress={this.handleLogin.bind(this)}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Logon</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Existing styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
        marginTop: 60
    },
    group: {
        alignItems: 'flex-start',
        padding: 10
    },
    input: {
        width: 150,
        padding: 2,
        paddingLeft: 5,
        borderColor: 'gray',
        borderWidth: 1
    },
    text: {
        padding: 0
    },
    button: {
        width: 150,
        backgroundColor: '#2299F2',
        padding: 15,
        marginTop: 20,
        borderRadius: 5
    },
    buttonText: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#fff',
        fontSize: 24
    },
});
```

I need to an ActivityIndicator to the above View, overlay the view, and center the ActivityIndicator.

Comment: Tried React Native Loading Spinner Overlay and whole app stopped scrolling. So removed it. And everything went normal.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

For this to work, you'd need to `absolute` position it, and render it *after* the elements that should be underneath the overlay:

```js
  loading: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
```

Then simply compose it into the `render` method conditionally, based on a  loading state. I am going to assume `this.handleLogin` sets some sort of loading state already.

Make sure it's rendered last so it takes precedence.

```js
...
{this.state.loading &&
    <View style={styles.loading}>
      <ActivityIndicator size='large' />
    </View>
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I added the background color `#F5FCFF88` to loading style to give the blurred overlay effect.

Comment: But ui is accessible :(

Comment: Add pointerEvents="none" to View made background non touchable.

Comment: it doesn't work for me, it does center horizontally, but vertically it is on top while the entire bottom part of the screen is empty...

Comment: ARgggh all this time I put the loader BEFORE my form, which just didn't work.. ..

Comment: @Dhrupal add a higher zIndex to the loading styles. eg: zIndex: 1000

Comment: pointerEvents="box-none" works for me.

Comment: simple, and basically it works!!! tks

Answer (score 31):

Here is a complete example using create react native app.

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, ActivityIndicator, View} from "react-native";

export default class Example extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {}

    render() {
        return (
            <View
                style={{flex: 1}}
            >
                  //Add other content here
                  {this.state.loading &&
                  <View style={styles.loading}>
                      <ActivityIndicator/>
                  </View>
                  }
                </View>
            );
        }
    }

    showLoading() {
       this.setState({loading: true})
    }

    hideLoading() {
       this.setState({loading: false})
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        loading: {
            position: 'absolute',
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            top: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            opacity: 0.5,
            backgroundColor: 'black',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center'
        }
    })
```

Comment: this works, but how do you enable/disable the background color?

Comment: @niksn I added showLoading and hideLoading functions for you

Comment: Thanks brother  it's help me alot

Answer (score 7):

You can use `StyleSheet.absoluteFill` to shorten code.
Add this to your render:

```js
<View style={styles.container}>
  //... other code here
  {this.state.loading && <View
      style={{
        ...StyleSheet.absoluteFill,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      }}>
      <ActivityIndicator />
  </View>}
</View>
```

Improvement:

You can also create a Loading component:

Loading.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import {View, ActivityIndicator, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

export const Loading = ({theme = 'white', size = 'large'}) => {
  const color = theme === 'white' ? '#00bdcd' : '#fff';
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        ...StyleSheet.absoluteFill,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      }}>
      <ActivityIndicator size={size} color={color} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Then use it anywhere you want

```js
<View style={styles.container}>
   //... other code here
   // remember to import Loading component
   {this.state.loading && <Loading />}
</View>
```

Comment: Great & elegant solution.

Answer (score 6):

You can build a nice overlay using the activity indicator component by also leveraging the modal capabilities like Sanaur suggests.

For example you can use the below functional component. You can control it's visibility through the `show` prop that you can tie to a state in your screen.

An example that you can adapt to your needs.

```
const ModalActivityIndicator = props => {
  const {
    show = false,
    color = "black",
    backgroundColor = "white",
    dimLights = 0.6,
    loadingMessage = "Doing stuff ..."
  } = props;
  return (
    <Modal transparent={true} animationType="none" visible={show}>
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center",
          backgroundColor: `rgba(0,0,0,${dimLights})`
        }}
      >
        <View
          style={{
            padding: 13,
            backgroundColor: `${backgroundColor}`,
            borderRadius: 13
          }}
        >
          <ActivityIndicator animating={show} color={color} size="large" />
          <Text style={{ color: `${color}` }}>{loadingMessage}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

and in your screen, in the render's return, just add it there as a child (please ignore the rest of the code, I put it there for context).

```
return (
<TouchableWithoutFeedback
  onPress={() => {
    Keyboard.dismiss();
  }}
>
  <View style={{ padding: 13, flex: 1}}>
    <ModalActivityIndicator show={screenIsWaiting} />
    <View
      style={{
```

where `screenIsWaiting` is just a state, for example

```
  const [screenIsWaiting, setScreenIsWaiting] = useState(false);
```

To test it you can add a button somewhere,

```
  <Button
    title="TestButton"
    onPress={async () => {
      setScreenIsWaiting(true);
      await sleep(5000);
      setScreenIsWaiting(false);
      ...
    }}
  />
```

where sleep is a function defined as

```
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

I found the sleep() idea on stackoverflow on another post.

You can of course also define the

```
<ModalActivityIndicator show={screenIsWaiting} ... />
```

only once in your App's root component and trigger it's display and props via a global state container like redux.

Answer (score 4):

There is a library available for this [react-native-loading-spinner-overlay](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-loading-spinner-overlay).
You can simply install it using

```
npm install react-native-loading-spinner-overlay --save
```

and can import into your project using

```
import Spinner from 'react-native-loading-spinner-overlay';
```

Here is how to use it

```
<Spinner
  //visibility of Overlay Loading Spinner
  visible={this.state.loading}
  //Text with the Spinner 
  textContent={'Loading...'}
  //Text style of the Spinner Text
  textStyle={styles.spinnerTextStyle}
/>
```

[image]  [image]

Comment: this library seems to be working fine in terms of full overlay and disabling user interaction.

Answer (score 4):

**STEP 1:**
Create the component for the spinner:

```
export const OverlaySpinner = () => {
 return (
    <View style={styles.spinnerView}>
      <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
    </View>
  );   
 };
```

**STEP 2:**

Create the style for the spinner view (using zIndex is very important to make sure the view is over everything on the screen):

```
spinnerView: {
    position: "absolute",
    zIndex: 1,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF88",
  },
```

**STEP 3:**

Make the initial state for the spinning component:

```
const [showSpinner, setshowSpinner] = useState(true);
```

**STEP 4:**

Use the component and don't forget to import it (don't forget to dismiss the keyboard on submit)

```
{showSpinner && <OverlaySpinner />}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you should use Modal to overlay activity indicator. Following is an example:

```
<Modal
transparent={true}
animationType={'none'}
visible={loading}
onRequestClose={() => {console.log('close modal')}}>
<View style={styles.modalBackground}>
<View style={styles.activityIndicatorWrapper}>
<ActivityIndicator
animating={loading} />
</View>
</View>
</Modal>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add in view of loading

```
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
```

Answer (score 0):

set in View of Activity Indicator

position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'

Answer (score 0):

Here my code for a functional component for anyone looking to achieve this with nativebase as design system. `useColorScheme` is another hook I use for detecting dark mode.

```
import { Flex, Spinner } from "native-base"
import React from "react"
import useColorScheme from "../../hooks/useColorScheme"

export default function Loading() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme()

  return (
    <Flex
      position="absolute"
      alignItems="center"
      justifyContent="center"
      top={0}
      left={0}
      right={0}
      bottom={0}
      backgroundColor={colorScheme === "dark" ? "coolBlack.500" : "white"}
    >
      <Spinner size="lg" color={colorScheme === "dark" ? "white" : "coolBlack.500"} />
    </Flex>
  )
}
```