# Unwanted bottom margin in KeyboardAwareScrollView- ReactNative

Tags: react-native

I'm using following style for the loading view(Last child).

`overlay: {
    flex: 1,
    zIndex:2,
    position: 'absolute',
    height:HEIGHT,//(HEIGHT & WIDTH obtained from Dimensions)
    width:WIDTH,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    opacity: 0.5,
    alignItems:'center',
    justifyContent:'center',
  }`

This view should cover whole screen. But at bottom some margin is there.

[image: ScreenShot]

How to remove it?

SOLUTION: Actually problem with KeyboardAwareScrollView. I solved it by giving contentContainerStyle={{flex:1}}

```
<KeyboardAwareScrollView
  style={styles.scrollView}
  resetScrollToCoords={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
  contentContainerStyle={{flex:1}}
  scrollEnabled={true}>
 //All children
<LoadingView style={styles.overlay}/>
</KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```

[image]

Comment: I guess the HEIGHT is calculated without the status bar.

Comment: For a simple overlay please see my answer here, just add your `backgroundColor` and `opacity` or `backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'` -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046500/how-do-i-overlay-activityindicator-in-react-native/44046858#44046858