# Disable everything and place an ActivityIndicator in front of it in React Native

Tags: button, react-native, activity-indicator

I have a button which calls a fetch, but I can still press the button while the fetch is running. I want to disable this button (and all inputs if possible) and place an ActivityIndicator in front of it.

Is there an option for this in the ActivityIndicator? 
My current ActivityIndicator looks like this. It is only displayed, when I set `this.state.animating` to `true`.

```
<ActivityIndicator
    animating={this.state.animating}
    style={{marginTop: 80}}
    size="large"
/>
```

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44046858/7772870) answere, but it seems like the button won't get disabled as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<Button>` component supports `disabled` flag. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button.html#disabled. You can use it like this in your case.

```
<Button disabled={this.state.animating}>
```