# React Native How to block all the UI Interaction while Activity indicator is opened?

Tags: react-native

I am using activity indicator in my code and it is working fine. but now i want to block all the UI interactions while activity indicator is opened.

Comment: please provide code or example

Comment: you can do like this
 render() {
 (this.state.data){ return <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" /> } else { 
return (<view> <Text>hello</Text></View> ) }

Comment: But I have to show Activity Indicator on the top of the View

Comment: Have you tried rendering a full screen transparent `Modal` component while the Activity Indicator is showing?

Comment: @User10001
is solve your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve

**First way**

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        if(this.props.isLoginLoading){
            return(
                <ActivityIndicatorMode/>
            )
        }

        return (
             <View />
        )
    }
}
```

**Second way**

[react-native-loading-spinner-overlay](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-loading-spinner-overlay)
you can use above library to use progress with background ui.

[Refer Example](https://github.com/joinspontaneous/react-native-loading-spinner-overlay/blob/master/example/App.js)

you can use conditioning rendering when your `isLoginLoading` is true it will show indicator otherwise render your actual code and you are not able to interacting in UI.

Comment: As per your example only one this is visible at a time eith Ui or Activity indicator. but my requirement is to show activity indicator on the top of the UI

Comment: @User10001 check my edited answers 
it will definitely achieve your requirements.
if it will help please accept my answers so another user get right solution
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can block the UI with [pointerEvents](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#pointerevents)

Answer (score 0):

For blocking touches on the entire view we can use `pointerevents`

[Click here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#pointerevents) for complete explanation.

Usage would be like this

```
{loading && <View style={styles.spinner} pointerEvents={'none'}>
        <ActivityIndicator/>
    </View>
}
```

Comment: i have to show it in the top of the UI and it will work only when i use pointerEvents={'none'} with parent view and i do not know how to use it

Comment: Try to add this pointerEvents = {‘none’} in the top view which covers whole screen and in the style attribute of view add flex:1.

Comment: okay, when after 10 seconds when loading variable become false and Activity indicator disappear then how i can make the top view again clickable

Comment: you can try solution in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046500/how-do-i-overlay-activityindicator-in-react-native

Answer (score 0):

If you want to block all UI interaction while activity indicator is working, then add a style of ActivityIndicatior.Use this as below example:-
    `style={{flex: 1}}`

```html
render() {
 return (
  <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
  <ImageBackground source={AppImages.welcome.source} style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
  {!!this.state.data &&<View style={styles.container}>{this.renderContent()}</View>}
  {!this.state.data &&this.renderHUD()}
  </ImageBackground>
   </View>
  );
 }
  
  renderHUD() {
     return <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#ffffff"
           style={{justifyContent: 'flex-end',
     alignItems: 'center',
     flex: 1,
     marginBottom: '12.4%'}} />;
  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make new component for activity indicator like below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { View, ActivityIndicator,Dimensions } from 'react-native';

export default class Loader extends Component {
    render() {
        const { isVisible } = this.props;
        return (
            isVisible ?
                <View style={{
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                position: 'absolute',
                height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
                width:  Dimensions.get('window').width,
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center'}} >
                    <ActivityIndicator size="small" color={'red'} />
                </View> : null
        );
    }
}
```

Add component like below:

```
import { Loader } from 'path of component';


render(){
  return(
 <View>
     ...
     ...
      //put loader compponent ar the bottom
     <Loader isVisible={isLoginLoading: true OR false} />
 </View
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
render() {
    const RenderView = Loading ? <ActivityIndicator style={{flex:1}}/> : <ScreenView/>;
    return RenderView;
}
```